# Basis of the rows space after multiplication with an orthonormal matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthonormal

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$. Given another **column orthonormal** matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times \ell}$.
Now wo do dimensionality reduction of matrix $A$ using $R$ as follows:
$$B = R^T A \in \mathbb{R}^{\ell \times m}$$.

My question is the following: Is the row space of $B$ spanned by the same basis as the row space of $A$? (If so, why is this true?)